# What is right offset calculation to scroll to my desired widget inside a webpage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Stuck in another chaos for days, your guidance and help would be appreciated.

I have added following **code that works fine in scrolling when I scroll from Home Widget.** But **when i scroll from any other widget, it doesnt work fine**, like lets say right now am viewing About Us section and i click portfolio from side navbar (drawer in my case), instead of being taken to portfolio am taken to home/or any  other random location on webpage.

So basically **following code works only if am currently on Home Widget. Otherwise it doesn't work properly. and so doesnt take me to required widget location**

***Is their a better way***

or ***how to fix this current code*** so that wherever i am, when i click a link from drawer, the webpage is scrolled to that widget.

Adding complete code below for better understanding.

```
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = "homepage.dart";
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  final GlobalKey section1Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section2Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section3Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section4Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section5Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section6Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section7Key = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey section8Key = GlobalKey();

  String currentSectionTitle = '';

  // Function to scroll to a specific section based on its key
  void _scrollToSection(int sectionIndex) {
    GlobalKey? sectionKey;
    String sectionTitle = '';

    if (sectionIndex == 0) {
      sectionKey = section1Key;
      sectionTitle = 'H O M E';
    } else if (sectionIndex == 1) {
      sectionKey = section2Key;
      sectionTitle = 'A B O U T  U S';
    }
    else if (sectionIndex == 2) {
      sectionKey = section3Key;
      sectionTitle = 'S E R V I C E S';
    }
    else if (sectionIndex == 3) {
      sectionKey = section4Key;
      sectionTitle = 'S T A T S';
    }
    else if (sectionIndex == 4) {
      sectionKey = section5Key;
      sectionTitle = 'W H Y  U S';
    }
    else if (sectionIndex == 5) {
      sectionKey = section6Key;
      sectionTitle = 'P O R T F O L I O';
    }
    else if (sectionIndex == 6) {
      sectionKey = section7Key;
      sectionTitle = 'R E VI E W S';
    }
    else if (sectionIndex == 7) {
      sectionKey = section8Key;
      sectionTitle = 'C O N T A C T  U S';
    }

    // Only proceed if a valid sectionKey is found
    if (sectionKey != null) {
      final RenderBox renderBox = sectionKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero).dy;

      _controller.animateTo(
        offset,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      );

      // Update the current section title in the app bar
      updateCurrentSectionTitle(sectionTitle);
    } else {
      print('Section key is null for sectionIndex: $sectionIndex');
    }
  }

  void updateCurrentSectionTitle(String title) {
    setState(() {
      currentSectionTitle = title;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      return Scaffold(
        drawer: (screenWidth < 650) ? MobileNavbar(
          scrollToSectionCallback: _scrollToSection,
        ) : null,
        appBar: (screenWidth < 650) ? AppBar(
          title: Text(currentSectionTitle, style: TextStyle(color: kGreyColor),),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: kSecondaryColor,
          ),
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,) : null,
        backgroundColor: kAccentColor,
        body: ResposniveLayout(
          DesktopBody: DesktopSite(),
          TabletBody: TabletSite(),
          MobileBody: MobileSite(
            scrollController: _controller,
            section8Key: section8Key,
            section1Key: section1Key,
            section2Key: section2Key,
            section3Key: section3Key,
            section4Key: section4Key,
            section5Key: section5Key,
            section6Key: section6Key,
            section7Key: section7Key,
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please only post the minimum reproducible example of code required to make the bug happen. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example